# Roving Crown vs. Charly Point - what's the difference?

Tags: archery, arrows, roving

TopHat has two roving points in its range. One is the Roving Crown...

[image: Roving Crown]

... and the other is called Charly Point.

[image: Charly Point]

They seem to have an identical concept but still the Crown costs three times as much as the Charly. What are the advantages of the crown compared to the charlies?